# Merge Separate Query Results into One Result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following queries:

```
db.orders.find({ currency: 'ils' }).sort({ percent: -1 }).limit(1);
db.orders.find({ currency: 'usd' }).sort({ percent: -1 }).limit(1);
db.orders.find({ currency: 'eur' }).sort({ percent: -1 }).limit(1);
```

I'd like to get a single result with the 3 documents that those queries results. In other words, combine the results into one result. Any idea how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/), preceded by [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/):

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "currency": { "$in": [ "ils", "usd", "eur" ] }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "currency": 1, "percent": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$currency",
    "doc": {  "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }}
])
```

Optionally [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) for the `"doc"` if needed ( [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) requires you "explicitly" name all document properties you want ):

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "currency": { "$in": [ "ils", "usd", "eur" ] }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "currency": 1, "percent": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$currency",
    "doc": {  "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" } }
])
```

The basic concept is [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) works like [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) for a single property argument and is effectively "shorthand" for the longer statement. This selects documents many "any" of the supplied values and no others.

In the "long" form the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) is effectively:

```
{
  "$or": [
    { "currency": "ils" },
    { "currency": "usd" },
    { "currency": "eur" }
  ]
}
```

So you can see more clearly now it's just like "writing three queries, since you get "this" OR "that" OR "the other" as what comprises the selected results.

The [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) is much the same as you are doing, except you "prefix" by the "currency" considering you are fetching all supplied, and not just one.

The [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) natuarally takes the **first** document content from the grouping boundary, which is "currency". We can supply `$$ROOT` as an alternative to naming all the document properties in argument to the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) accumulator individually.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer! Is this a single request to the db? Which indexes can make this query efficient?

Comment: @Naor There is on'y **one** field in the query, which is `"currency"`. Aggregation pipelines cannot use an index at any stage beyond the first. From MongoDB 3.6 we can "hint" the query, to ensure the `"percent"` in the `$sort` stage is picked up as well, if you have a compound index on those two fields, in the order presented.